# Show all products from root category

Tags: magento2.4

Exists a way to show all products from all categories in a page in Magento 2.4.6?

for example `www.mymagento.com/all-products.html`

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can try to create one parent category and play with Anhor config in display settings.(https://prnt.sc/TzprhW1mJhbq)

https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/what-is-the-magento-2-anchor-category.html